# Reading from a textfile in a certain format

Tags: c, text-files, filestream

I am trying to read from file in this order: 0 0 4 (100) 12 (67) 2

this correspondes to:

process id, arrival_time, 1st_CPU_burst, (1st_IO_burst), 2nd_CPU_burst, (2nd_IO_burst)

This has something to do with operating system fundamentals I am trying to perform fcfs scheduling with a queue but before I do that I have to read correctly.

In my code I am trying to only read numbers with brackets around them and print the same input such as (200) but it does not work because it doesnt recognize the brackets. This is for debugging purposes, but I am going to be following the format above.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char input;
    char b1;
    char b2;
    FILE *f = fopen("CPULoad.dat", "r");

     while(fscanf(f, "%s%s%s", &b1, &input, &b2) == 1)
     {


        printf("%s%s%s", &b1, &input, &b2);

      }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: None of those input parameters are appropriate for `%s`, either coming or going. You need *arrays* of one form or another.

Comment: If you scan for 3 items, `fscanf` will return `3` if it succeeds in reading all 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, the best approach will be

1. Read the whole line from file using `fgets()`
2. Tokenize the input using `"()"` as delimiter.
3. Check the token for non-NULL.
4. use `strtol()` [or family] to convert the token to `int` or `long int`.

Note; Always check for the success of `fopen()` before using the returned pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to read 7 numbers from file, so your fscanf should looks like the following

```
fscanf(f, "%d %d %d (%d) %d (%d) %d", &process_id, &arrival_time, &_1st_CPU_burst, &_1st_IO_burst, &_2nd_CPU_burst, &_2nd_IO_burst, &other) == 7
```

If fscanf returns 7 all numbers were read, and can be processed.